# Which is the best option if I want to modify code from a previous REV in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I want to update to a previous REV and maybe change some code in that one. Which is the best way of doing it?

Should I create a Branch from that REV and make those changes on the Branch and after finishing merging with local?

Or should I just update to that REV, do the changes and merge right away?

Answer (score 1):

It's your choice anyway, but

- in case of `update|branch|commit|merge` you'll get named branch in history
- in case of `update|commit|merge` you'll get anonymous branch in history

You can also `hg clone -r REV`, made changes in clone, pull changes from clone, merge heads (anonymous branch again, but not single-repo, clones used as sources of branches)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make it clear if you're trying to correct a previous revision or create a new line of development. In the first case, you could use `hg histedit` or `hg commit --amend`. In the second case, probably a anonymous branch would suffice.